# Better understanding ngstorage on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

A page with a form where a user can add different entries multiple times before submitting. With each entry, some of the data entered is displayed in a table at the top as an overview and as the user goes through and enters all their entries, the full view allows the user to 'submit' when then would take each entry and 'submit' as a whole. So you could in essence, have 3 objects as such to submit.

```
var myObj1 = {
    firstname: "Nic",
    lastname: "Raboy",
    website: "http://blog.nraboy.com"
}

var myObj2 = {
    firstname: "Nic",
    lastname: "Raboy",
    website: "http://blog.nraboy.com"
}

var myObj3 = {
    firstname: "Nic",
    lastname: "Raboy",
    website: "http://blog.nraboy.com"
}
```

So the idea here in angular that I want to do is post all of this at once from cached data that the user has stored as mentioned above like a session state or html local storage. Being that I am using angular, was looking at ngstorage and was wondering what the best approach to this kind of scenario would be?

Keep in mind, there could be 1 object or 4 or 6 objects. So will want to push all.

Is using ngstorage better than using local storage? Read pros and cons of each and curious what others may think on this.

Lastly, is it best to store these objects as just individual objects or in an array containing objects?

Thanks much.

Comment: Anyone can something they can share here?

Answer (score 0):

Funny to see my name pop up here ;-)

To answer some of your questions:

1. Local storage and ngStorage are the same thing.  ngStorage is just a wrapper to make it more user friendly.  The wrapper serializes the information into local storage so you don't have to.
2. Should you store your cached data as objects or arrays?  This depends.  Are you going to be clearing the cache after the data has been sent to the server?  If yes, I'd recommend storing as an array because then you can just push new entries to the end of the array.  When it comes to key-value storage (local storage), you don't have a way to query the data (value) or figure out all the keys that might exist.  If you're not clearing the cache after uploading, I'd re-evaluate the situation and maybe use something like PouchDB.

Hopefully that clears things up?